# Can we make use of coupling capacitors in a circuit with big voltage swings at its nodes?

Tags: power-electronics

Can we make use of coupling capacitors in a circuit with big voltage swings at its nodes?
Do we need to utilize coupling capacitors in a power amplifier?  which we can do
away with a coupling capacitor in a power amplifier.

Comment: What do you mean by "make use of"? Coupling capacitors where? Across the supply rails? Between the output and loudspeaker? What problem are you trying to solve. Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The famous WIlliamson audio power amplifier, of vacuum tube fame, used 300 and 400 volt B+ rails.

There was ONE audio output transformer per amplifier.

Except for that last stage output, the other signal_path nodes were DC_blocked using capacitors.

With plate voltages along the load_line but up at 200 or 300 volts (thus about 100 volt drop across the plate load resistor, and grid voltages nominally at ZERO volts, the coupling capacitors had hundreds of volts across.